# Excel: Type mismatch

Tags: excel

i'm using this macro script:

```
Dim lister As String
Dim rowcounter As Integer
Dim v As Variant

rowcounter = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A2", Worksheets("1").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For Each v In Range("A2:A" + rowcounter)
lister = lister + "'" & CStr(v.Value) & "', "
Next
```

Debug.Print lister

This works fine so far but gives me a "type mismatch error".

Any idea why? Thank you guys!!

Comment: Use ampersand (&) instead of the plus sign (+) to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Dim sLister As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each rCell In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        sLister = sLister & ", " & "'" & CStr(rCell.Value) & "'"
    Next rCell
End With

sLister = Mid(sLister, 3)
```

Hope this helps!